# Is there any way to avoid deletion of duplicate load instruction when compiled using LLVM

Tags: llvm, llc

I am working on creating LLVM front-end module pass. So, Basically I need to duplicate all load instructions and store in a different register. At -O0 for clang, opt and llc tool, this duplicated load instruction is removed. I looked at the final assembly using objdump, I could see that duplicate load instruction was removed. I want a solution that somehow does not delete duplicate load instruction.

Actual C program is,

```cpp
int main(){
    int* p = (int *)(0x600000);//Some address
    int x=0x01, y=0x01;
    int z;
    z=x+y;
    *p=z;
}
```

The corresponding IR is,

```cpp
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %p = alloca i32*, align 8
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  %z = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32* inttoptr (i64 6291456 to i32*), i32** %p, align 8
  store i32 1, i32* %x, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %y, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %x, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1
  store i32 %add, i32* %z, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %z, align 4
  %3 = load i32*, i32** %p, align 8
  store i32 %2, i32* %3, align 4
  ret i32 0
}
```

But when my pass is enabled, this IR will change and I duplicate only load instructions with load address being same memory even for duplicated load.

The changed IR would be,

```cpp
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %p = alloca i32*, align 8
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  %z = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32* inttoptr (i64 6291456 to i32*), i32** %p, align 8
  store i32 1, i32* %x, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %y, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %x, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %x, align 4 //Added
  %3 = load i32, i32* %y, align 4 //Added
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1
  store i32 %add, i32* %z, align 4
  %4 = load i32, i32* %z, align 4
  %5 = load i32*, i32** %p, align 8
  %6 = load i32, i32* %z, align 4 //Added
  %7 = load i32*, i32** %p, align 8        //Added
  store i32 %4, i32* %5, align 4
  ret i32 0
}
```

I am able to see the changed IR at IR level but not at the final assembly level after llc. I think llc is removing all duplicated loads. How do I stop llc from removing?

Note: I tried making all variables volatile. For this it works, I am able to see duplicated loads after llc. But, this is not a proper solution. I cannot make all thousand variables volatile :(.

Comment: Making all variables volatile sounds like an easy search-and-replace, and `volatile` is an accurate description of the semantics you want.

Comment: Yea, I already did that. But, do you think there is any way apart from making volatile.

Comment: Perhaps, if you explain what you want and how it is different from having volatile variables. Programming languages (apart from perl) tend to have no more than one mechanism for each goal.

Comment: These instructions are deleted because they are unused, I think. Try "using" them in some way.

Comment: I used. Even then it is deleted. Compiler is smart enough at even -O0 level to remove the duplicated load.